# Visual studio 2012 shows other email address then computer account

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

Okay , i don't know where to put this but i have something strange going on when I fire up visual studio 2012.

So i was installing visual studio on my laptop and when I fired it up it said another email address then registered to my computer. (see image below)[image]
So I went looking for where the email came from but so far I don't have a single clue where the email comes from. It's not a second hand computer or so. Bought it a few months ago and been working in visual studio 2013. Today I had to install VS21012 to hve the right VS for this group project I'm working on.

Anyone got an idea where this could have came from and how to change it ?

Comment: You may want to blur or black out part of that e-mail address, especially since you say it's not yours. You should be fine leaving the "@hotmail.com" part, but I wouldn't keep the first bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Control panel > Credential Manager`

You can see this email address there.
You can remove the email address from the list and Visual studio ultimate will show you your own name (based on your current username in PC) or will tell you to fill the license key again.

Answer (score 0):

My Visual Studio do not show a mail-address. It shows Name and Company. This are the informations which I had to type in registration form while installing VS.

Answer (score 0):

Well did you check the windows 8 login data i.e to which mail-id your windows8 account integrated  ? The problem will be present here lol just becoz i faced it .

Once check it and get back i will try to assist you .

PS: HOTMAIL can be associated with windows 8 just becoz its microsoft's in my case it it outlook where both are same .

Comment: well are you sure , you never heard this guy name ? Yes i hope so you never heard . I only known solution for me maybe when you applied a license key the product key is registered to the mentioned mail-id . So did you buy it or else downloaded from some site ?

Comment: I bought the computer in the store so the windows was already installed on it

Comment: i am asking about visual studio now you working on ? did u made a purchase ? else ?

Comment: Ah no I'm working on a student developer license registered to my student email account

Comment: ok fine . Is this problem only with you or your colleges facing same thing .. have you checked it . re phrasing you words i.e you said you are student developer i guess you been given a product with some key to use it which is genuine .but key is officially registered with the mail id you are getting with Microsoft .. check with you mates

Comment: Their email is all fine otherwise I wouldn't ask on here

Comment: yes you are right . may be re-install the studio . not recommended but it will be a final option